# Grails: how to set a parameter for the whole group in UrlMappings

Tags: rest, grails, url-mapping, grails-2.5, urlmappings.groovy

Our Grails 2.5 web application has REST API.

We need to start a new version of the API so a group was created in `UrlMappings.groovy` like this:

```
group ("/v2") {

   "/documents"(resources: 'document') {
     "/meta"(resource: 'documentInfo', includes: ['show', 'update']) 
   }

   "/folders"(resources: 'folder')

   apiVersion = 2
}
```

The thing is that parameter `apiVersion` is not defined in `params` in controller actions.

The parameter is properly set if it is defined in each of the resources like this:

```
group ("/v2") {

   "/documents"(resources: 'document') {
     "/meta"(resource: 'documentInfo', includes: ['show', 'update']) {
       apiVersion = 2
     }
     apiVersion = 2
   }

   "/folders"(resources: 'folder') {
     apiVersion = 2
   }

}
```

How can I properly define a parameter on the group level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround will be using namespace... although my attempt to define it at group level wont work but you can give a try. But defining at resource level works even for nested resources.

```
group ("/v2") {

   "/documents"(resources: 'document', namespace:'v2') {
     "/meta"(resource: 'documentInfo', includes: ['show', 'update']) 
   }

   "/folders"(resources: 'folder', , namespace:'v2')
}
```